# Split en SQL de un select

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

Hola amigos tengo una consulta muy simple digamos que es

```
select puesto from puestos
```

y me devuelve lo siguiente

```
| 1 | Oficial Policiaco |

| 2 | Juez Amparo |

| 3 | etc etc |
```

Necesito separar este select y acomodarlo algo así

```
|  p1   |  p2       |

|Oficial| Policiaco |
```

los datos solo están separados por espacios, necesito ponerlos o bien en distintas variables o en distintos campos. Alguien sabe como hacer esto? y si puedo hacer **split** por espacios?

Comment: mmm vamos a ver si entendí. "juez" debería ir abajo de "oficial y "amparo" abajo de "policíaco"? o bien todo en columnas separadas?

Comment: umm separar "oficial policiaco" que esta en una soia columna a tenerlo ahora en 2? seguro que eso esta bien planteado?

Comment: Yo preguntaría, ¿por qué están juntos en la base de datos, cuando deberían estar separados? ¿No es acaso ese el problema?

Comment: ¿Siempre son solo 2 palabras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir de sql server 2016 existe el metodo STRING_SPLIT()

```
 SELECT ProductId, Name, value  
 FROM Product  
 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Tags, ',');
```

En ese ejemplo se perara por comas, lo cambiarías por espacio.
Fuente: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Si tu versión de sql server es menor tendrías que hacer algo asi:

```
 DECLARE @CADENA VARCHAR(100) = 'Oficial Policiaco'
 SELECT CHARINDEX(' ',@CADENA)
 SELECT SUBSTRING(@CADENA,0,LEN(@CADENA) - CHARINDEX(' ',@CADENA)), 
 SUBSTRING(@CADENA,CHARINDEX(' ',@CADENA),LEN(@CADENA)-CHARINDEX(' ',@CADENA)+1)
```

Espero te sirva